# I don't know how to fix an unary +: 'str' error

Tags: python

I have been attempting to write a game as an exercise in learning to use Python. I wrote a story into my code as a form of variable that is essentially a lot of other variables concatenated with strings to form the story.  However, when I run the code I get the error:

> TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'.

From what research I have done this seems to happen when something like a comma is in the wrong place or both a comma and a '+' are used at the same time accidentally.  I have checked my code and I don't see anything that might cause this problem.  Any help would be appreciated.

My code looks like this:

```
    story = (+name+ ",most doctors agree that bicycle " +verb_1+ " is a(n)) " +adj_1+
" form of exercise." +verb_2+ " a bicycle helps you develop your " +body_part+
"muscles as well as " +adverb+ " increasing the rate of your " +body_part_2+
" beat.  More " +noun+ " around the world " +verb_3+ " ride bicycles than ride "
+animal+ ".  No matter what kind of " +noun_2+ " you " +verb_4+
", always be sure to wear a(n) " +adj_2+ "helmet.  Make sure to have "
+color+ " reflectors too!")

print(story)
```

Comment: Why do you start with `+name`? Except when used at the beginning of a number, `+` has to be between things that you're adding or concatenating.

Comment: Just change `(+name` to `(name`

Comment: I suggest you use an f-string instead of all that concatenation. It's much easier to read and write.

Answer (score 2):

A minimal example of what you're seeing:

```
>>> +"hello"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
>>>
```

The *unary* `+` operator only works for numbers. In this case, you need to switch `+name` to `name`.

Or use an f-string.

```
>>> name = "Bob"
>>> f"Hi, {name}"
'Hi, Bob'
>>>
```

Comment: Well, "unary" kind of covers that. Edited to emphasize unary.

Comment: Sorry, misread.

Comment: Happens to the best of us. :)